# What would make video streaming work in one environment and not in another? (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jwplayer

So, I have an application that lets users upload videos/stream videos. I've chosen to use [Pandastream](http://www.pandastream.com) for this so that I won't have to re-write all of the video upload, and encoding logic that  [Pandastream](http://www.pandastream.com) already handles out of the box.

For the actual streaming of the videos [Pandastream](http://www.pandastream.com) suggests that you use [JWPlayer](http://www.jwplayer.com) along side Amazon AWS's [CloudFront distribution](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). So, I've done just that and my code for playing videos is:

```
    <script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/Nu3Cav_oEeKU_RIxOUCPzg.js"></script>
    <div id='my-video<%= video.id %>'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jwplayer('my-video<%= video.id %>').setup({
            playlist: [{
                    image: "<%= video.thumbnail_url %>",
                    sources: [
                        { file: "<%= saas_admin_video_url(video.remote_id, :smil) %>" },
                        { file: "<%= saas_admin_video_url(video.remote_id, :m3u8) %>" }
                    ]
                }],
            primary: "flash",
            width: '100%',
            rtmp: {
                    bufferlength: 2
                }
        });
    </script>

</div>
```

**The Problem:**

The issue I'm facing is that the video streams/plays perfectly fine in development mode but doesn't play at all in production, and just loads and loads endlessly instead without ever actually playing.

I've factored out this being an asset precompile issue as all of the data is stored on Pandastream, and the videos are uploading just fine to Amazon S3.

I've also considered that it might be a crossdomain.xml issue but I've used the allow full access syntax:

```
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
```

Which essentially makes the app fully accessible, so that's ruled out.

At this point, I'm not sure what else it could be?

edit:

"When I run in our wizard – http://www.jwplayer.com/wizard/

production: http://rocky-depths-3714.herokuapp.com/videos/cdea8d3029fcadcdc867632e2dea1558.smil

I get:

```
Cache-Control max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection keep-alive
Date Mon, 23 Jun 2014 01:53:17 GMT
Etag “8c42bcfab3b3ad441690b068862c6d6f”
Server WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.1/2014-02-24)
X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
X-Request-Id f1633dd3-8c9e-4709-a70c-14e024064389
X-Runtime 0.073537
X-UA-Compatible chrome=1
X-XSS-Protection 1; mode=block
x-frame-options SAMEORIGIN
```

development: http://multi.t.proxylocal.com/videos/afe07fa677cd4a44f1e1f89262981d10.smil

```
Cache-Control max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Length 492
Content-Type application/smil; charset=utf-8
Date Mon, 23 Jun 2014 01:53:57 GMT
Etag “c77ba1535b98337a54efb7ab1bbabafc”
Server WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.1/2014-02-24)
X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
X-Request-Id a0008a01-1a15-4860-bfcf-34d6b9b66838
X-Runtime 2.490657
X-UA-Compatible chrome=1
X-XSS-Protection 1; mode=block
x-frame-options SAMEORIGIN
```

You notice that the dev one has a few other options?

Content-Length 492
Content-Type application/smil; charset=utf-8

These are absent from the calls from the production one.

It seems like the length missing means the player has no idea how long the file is and is not able to stream it properly. The type is also missing. How can I make sure both dev and production are identical here?"

Comment: are the video URLs being passed into the `sources` valid in production?

Comment: To me, this seems like you need to make sure to add the content-type (mime-type), and content-length, on production. Since you set up both the dev and production servers, shouldn't it be fairly straightforward to add these? I haven't really used rails before though so I am not sure of the specifics that would entail.